# How can I group a Pandas DataFrame on a conditional?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to use a conditional `groupby` on a pandas DF.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(9), 'B':['this','this','this','that','and','the','other','thing','.']})
```

Group 'A' by whether 'B' == 'this' (how I imagine this w/ a query structure):

```
test['A'].groupby("B == 'this'").sum()
```

should return this: [3,33]

```
pd.Series([3,33])
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*groupby* works if you pass it another series of same length, so you can calculate the condition series firstly and then group by it:

```
test.groupby(test.B == "this").sum()
#        A
#    B  
#False  33
# True   3
```